# Access list member in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table which has one-item list objects in a certain column:

```
require(data.table)
col <- c(list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")),
         list(c("A", "B", "E", "F")),
         list(c("B", "C", "D", "E")))
dt <-  data.table(a = c("Jon", "Josh", "Laura"), b = col, c = c(1, 2, 3))
```

What I'd like to do is to add a column `plainstring` to `dt` which contains the string from the "b" column. I tried

```
dt[, plainstring := b[.I][[1]]]
```

but that doesn't work (I guess a misunderstanding of .I). Any ideas?

The desired output would be

```
> dt
       a         b c plainstring
1:   Jon A,B,C,D,E 1   A,B,C,D,E
2:  Josh   A,B,E,F 2     A,B,E,F
3: Laura   B,C,D,E 3     B,C,D,E
```

where for every row `i`, `dt$plainstring[i]` is a character vector and equals `unlist(dt$b[i])`.

Comment: If it is the first element of each list item `dt[, plainstring:= unlist(lapply(b, `[`,1))]` or `dt[, plainstring:=unlist(b)[1], by=c]`

Comment: `dt[,plainstring:=toString(unlist(b)), by=c]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your update it looks like you want something like this:

```
dt[, plainstring := vapply(b, toString, "")][]
#        a         b c   plainstring
# 1:   Jon A,B,C,D,E 1 A, B, C, D, E
# 2:  Josh   A,B,E,F 2    A, B, E, F
# 3: Laura   B,C,D,E 3    B, C, D, E
```

which reduces the `b` column to a length three character vector.

```
dt[, plainstring]
# [1] "A, B, C, D, E" "A, B, E, F"    "B, C, D, E"
```

If you'd like it without the spaces, then `paste()` would be more appropriate in the `vapply()` call above.

```
vapply(b, paste, "", collapse = ",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
  dt[,plainstring:=toString(b[[1L]]),by=1:nrow(dt)]

  dt
  #      a         b c   plainstring
  #1:   Jon A,B,C,D,E 1 A, B, C, D, E
  #2:  Josh   A,B,E,F 2    A, B, E, F
  #3: Laura   B,C,D,E 3    B, C, D, E

  dt$plainstring
  #[1] "A, B, C, D, E" "A, B, E, F"    "B, C, D, E"
```